# sed doesn't remove characters from UTF range properly

Tags: linux, sed, utf-8

I want to clear my file from all characters except russian and arabic letters, "|" and space mark. Lets start with only arabic letters. So I have:

```
cat file.tzt | sed 's/[^\u0600-\u06FF]//g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 21: Invalid range end.
```

I have tried [\u0621-\u064A] - same.
I also tried to use {Arabic}, but it doesn't clean files properly at all.

Error looks kinda strange for me. Obviously, 064FF > 0621.

So, overall I want to have something like this:

```
cat file.tzt | sed 's/[^\u0600-\u06FFа-яА-Я |]//g'
```

And I am ok with awk or any other utility, but as I know sed is stable and reliable.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl understands UTF-8:

```
perl -CSD -pe 's/[^\N{U+0600}-\N{U+06FF}]//g' -- file.txt
```

- `-C` turns of UTF-8 support, `S` means for stdin/stdout/stderr, `D` means for any i/o streams.

You can also use Unicode properties:

```
s/\P{Cyrillic}//g
```

Comment: Works with arabic, thx. But doesn't removes digits and punctuation marks. And it made a one-line file, so '\n' is removed also. And I tried 's/[^\N{U+0600}-\N{U+06FF}\P{Cyrillic}]//g' - it removed all Russian characters. Not sure what to do. But I think I can add codes ranges instead of {Cyrillic}. But what I can do with '\n'?

Comment: Can you provide some data to test the solution against?

Comment: Yeah, everything works fine. I just added range for a cyrillic:   s/[^\N{U+0600}-\N{U+06FF}\N{U+0410}-\N{U+044F} '\n']//g